# Login attempt with python

Tags: python, html, authentication, mechanize

How do I know whether the login worked or not? I know that req.read returns the HTML page, do I have to compare the HTML pages or what?

Here's the code:

```
import urllib2
import cookielib
import urllib
import requests
import mechanize
from mechanize._opener import urlopen
from mechanize._form import ParseResponse
from Tkconstants import BROWSE


EMAIL = raw_input('Inserisci la tua mail: ')
PASSWORD = raw_input('Inserisci la password: ')

URL = 'https://' +raw_input('Inserici il sito:')

def main():
    browser = mechanize.Browser()
    browser.set_handle_robots(False)
    browser.open(URL +'/login.php?')
    browser.select_form(nr = 0)
    browser.form['email'] = EMAIL
    browser.form['pass'] = PASSWORD
    req=browser.submit()
    print req.read()

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Yes, yes you do

Comment: Depends. You might be able to determine a successful login by the HTTP status code returned, although this can be incorrect as well since some sites may give you a 200 and tell you nicely you don't have the correct credentials and others might give you a 401. Depends on how the server is setup. For 401s to be returned there *must* be a WWW-Authenticate header field sent.

Comment: ok, in order to compare the html codes i need to create a file with the html code inside? Other ideas?

Comment: Usually when you're logged in there will be a "logout" link, and when you're logged out there will be a "login" link.

Comment: thanks, it works!!